# Get the scanned image of barcode using zxing barcode scanner?

Tags: android, sencha-touch-2, phonegap-plugins

I have successfully integrated zxing Barcode scanner with Phonegap+sencha touch app. Now i have to capture the image also during the scan and return it to the view.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score -1):

With ZXing APIs, you can implement it yourself. About how to use Android camera, please refer to [Android website](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html). Here is the code for capturing images from preview callback, as well as how to use zxing to decode the image:

```
private Camera.PreviewCallback mPreviewCallback = new PreviewCallback() {

        @Override
        public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (mDialog.isShowing())
                return;

            LuminanceSource source = new PlanarYUVLuminanceSource(data, mWidth, mHeight, mLeft, mTop, mAreaWidth, mAreaHeight, false);
            BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(
              source));
            Result result;

            try {
                result = mMultiFormatReader.decode(bitmap, null);
                if (result != null) {
                    mDialog.setTitle("Result");
                    mDialog.setMessage(result.getText());
                    mDialog.show();
                }
            } catch (NotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
```

For more detailed information, you can read the article [How to implement a simple barcode scan application on Android](http://www.codepool.biz/ocr-barcode-twain/how-to-implement-a-simple-barcode-scan-application-on-android.html)